# How can you coalesce a datetimeoffset in Linq to SQL?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a Linq query that orders by a datetimeoffest. The goal is to have the one that is NULL at the top, followed by most recent, 2nd recent, and so on. I started with this.

```
orderby item.Date descending
```

Doing it this way the NULLs go to the bottom. So I changed it to this.

```
orderby (item.Date.HasValue ? item.Date.Value.Ticks : long.MaxValue) descending
```

That works for in memory queries, but doesn't translate to SQL. My latest attempt is this.

```
orderby (item.Date.HasValue ? item.Date : new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(9999, 09, 31))) descending
```

The issue here is the max datetimeoffset is not the same between SQL and C#. I feel like I am missing an obvious easy solution.

Any input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a datetime I noticed you couldn't use DateTime.Max and pass that to SQL. Seems the max datetime in SQL is lower than C#. I assumed the same applied in DateTimeOffset. That does not appear to be true. It would appear this code works.

```
orderby (item.Date.HasValue ? item.Date : DateTimeOffset.MaxValue) descending
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried C#'s coalesce operator?

```
orderby (item.Date ?? DateTimeOffset.MaxValue) descending
```

Comment: Yeah, I am pretty sure it doesn't work I think you may be able to do orderby (item.Value ?? DateTimeOffset.MaxValue) descending, it doesn't really return a DateTimeoffset, it returns a System.Nullable<System.DateTimeOffset>